# Rails 4 + Ember-Auth + Devise Starter Kit for Ember.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ember.js, ember-data

Been using this guide: https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth-rails-demo to set up a starter kit for rails 4 + ember-auth + devise + bootstrap

I'm getting this error:
`` undefined local variable or method `build_resource' for #<SessionsController:0x007ffd4783b9d0> ``

and my console gives me:
`` NameError (undefined local variable or method `build_resource' for #<SessionsController:0x007ffd4783b9d0>):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:5:in `create' ``

Here is the link to my public repo: https://github.com/amaanr/ember-rails4-starter-kit/tree/ember-auth
feel free to clone and make sure to do a `rake db:create`, `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:seed`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been having the same issue. To fix it, I needed to look at the Devise source code and found [this diff](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/8a93c340802c9674cfcc39eec12793bd63cf5776#diff-5). Also, Devise no longer defines `build resource` in the base `DeviseController`. It is only defined in the `RegistrationsController`.

To fix it, I basically copied the `new` method from [sessions_controller.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L6-L11) (because that was basically what the guide did). Another option would be to change your `Gemfile` to require a previous version of Devise.

Comment: Thanks you, this helped a lot! Check out my work in progress: https://github.com/amaanr/ember-rails4-starter-kit